# Decimal Data in Varchar datatype - Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric

Tags: sql, math, overflow

```
select 
T1.Col1,
CASE T1.Col1
   WHEN 99.95 THEN '18.97'
END 
from Table T1
```

When I execute the above SQL query I get the below error message:

**`Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.`**

The datatype of the column `T1.Col1` is `Varchar` but holds data for ex: 18.97. Poor design but have to live with it.

I have tried many ways to get this code working before posting here. For ex I tried to convert the data into varchar, decimal also tried to see if I could use character instead of decimal values, also tried to use cast function.

Please help.

This is SQL Server 2005. Sorry for not sharing this earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try any of the below:

1. Try using single quotes for case value (Since T1.col1 is a varchar)

   ```
   select 
   T1.Col1,
   CASE T1.Col1
      WHEN '99.95' THEN '18.97'
   END 
   from Table T1
   ```
2. Try converting the varchar string (T1.col1) to number before checking case condition using TO_NUMBER function

   ```
   select 
   T1.Col1,
   CASE TO_NUMBER(T1.Col1, '99.99') 
      WHEN 99.95 THEN '18.97'
   END 
   from Table T1
   ```

Comment: select T1.Col1, case CONVERT(DECIMAL, LTRIM(RTRIM(T1.Col1)))
         WHEN '99.99' THEN 18.97 END from Table T1. This worked for me. Many thanks for driving the idea around this concept. I guess working on cross platform does help. :)